# How to use t() function with node_load in custom drupal module?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am using a custom module for my site, and I am using node_load to get the field value of type "long text" field and field of value of type "text".

Something like this

$com_types = "".$ucom->node_title."";

How should I translate $ucom->node_title ?

t() function does not translate variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Node translation should be done at the node level.  the t() function is for labeling elements of the interface and theme things.

You should look at multi-language node translation modules,  [this link is helpful](https://www.drupal.org/node/1498708)

You'd first want to use something like this:  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_get_translations/7

It'll let you get the NIDs of the translated versions of the node you want,  then you can use node_load() to get the translated version.

Comment: I am performing node_load so how can I do that on node level or did you mean get the translated version of node and then I should do node_load ?

Comment: @MohitWadhwa  more detail added in an edit.

Comment: Though, exactly your recommendation on drupal API did not solve my problem but yeah it gave me a way. 
I appreciate your help. 
So Thanks.